# Why does Django 1.7's storage remove non-word characters from file names?

Tags: django, django-1.7

I'm using the standard Django 1.7 `FileField` for one of my models. Whenever someone uploads a file, the name changes from something that looks nice (e.g., "Some & File Name.xls") to something that looks incredibly ugly (e.g., "Some_File_Name.xls"). This is done in the storage class which, in turn, calls `django.utils.text.get_valid_filename`. See code below:

```
def get_valid_filename(s):
    """
    Returns the given string converted to a string that can be used for a clean
    filename. Specifically, leading and trailing spaces are removed; other
    spaces are converted to underscores; and anything that is not a unicode
    alphanumeric, dash, underscore, or dot, is removed.
    >>> get_valid_filename("john's portrait in 2004.jpg")
    'johns_portrait_in_2004.jpg'
    """
    s = force_text(s).strip().replace(' ', '_')
    return re.sub(r'(?u)[^-\w.]', '', s)
```

It seems to me that most systems can handle many non-word characters just fine at this point. Any thoughts on why the file name is being escaped in this manner?

Comment: I think the idea is to be encoding-agnostic in the database and not have problems on comparisson.

Comment: If that were the case, wouldn't they just remove non-unicode characters? They are removing all non-word characters.

Comment: characters like " are not unicode but not allowed in filenames

Comment: That may be true of " with some OSes (not OSX, however). That said, I'm less concerned about the " going away and more about the spaces being replaced with underscores.